# Tapir, Circe, Snakecase

Tags: json, scala, circe, snakecasing, tapir

I have a code below

```
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.Encoder
import io.circe.generic.extras._, io.circe.syntax._

implicit val config: Configuration = Configuration.default.withSnakeCaseMemberNames

case class User(firstName: String, lastName: String)

print(User("Foo", "McBar").asJson)
```

Its supposed to output something like

```
{
  "first_name" : "Foo",
  "last_name" : "McBar"
}
```

But I get

```
{
  "firstName" : "Foo",
  "lastName" : "McBar"
}
```

what Am I doing wrong? i thought giving implicit config will be enough !!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`import io.circe.generic.auto._` does **not** use `Configuration`.

If you want to use configration you have to use `io.circe.generic.extras.auto._`.

Generic extras (`io.circe.generic.extras`) is not *an extension* to standard derivation (`io.circe.generic`) but *an alternative*, and they don't mix well in the same file if you use `auto`.